# Resource leak warning in eclipse when extending ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks

I use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to fill a byte array with different values of different length in bytes. I use the method `write(byte[] b)`. As this method is inherited from `OutputStream` it could throw an IOException. In `ByteArrayOutputStream` there is a method `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` which don't throw an IOException, so I extend `ByteArrayOutputStream` and override the `write(byte[] b)` method which now also don't throw an IOException:

```
  private class ByteArrayOutputStreamNoException extends ByteArrayOutputStream
  {

      public ByteArrayOutputStreamNoException(int size)
      {
          super(size);
      }

      public ByteArrayOutputStreamNoException()
      {
          super();
      }

      @Override
      public void write(byte[] data)
      {
          write(data, 0, data.length);
      }
  }
```

With the extended class I get now in eclipse 4.5.1 a warning of a resource leak, as I don't close the stream in the code. This was not the case with `ByteArrayOutputStream`. What is wrong with my extended class or what do I have to add to it to remove the warning? I know I could add the `SuppressWarnings` annotation to each instantiation of the stream but I prefer to change the extended class somehow to remove the warning.

Comment: Which version of java is this ? I copied it and it didnt show any warnings for jdk 1.8

Comment: I use also jdk 1.8.0_66. Then its maybe eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse has a list of classes in the standard Java libraries which are known not to need the resource leak warning, `ByteArrayOutputStream` is one of these. There is a long description of this in Eclipse bug [358903](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358903).

The code implementing this is the `applyCloseableClassWhitelists` method of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding`. The list of classes is hard coded and cannot be extended.

When you extend the `ByteArrayOutputStream` class Eclipse can no longer be sure that the `close` is not needed so you get the warning.

You could use the 'try-with-resources' style try statement to work around this:

```java
try
 (ByteArrayOutputStreamNoException stream = new ByteArrayOutputStreamNoException())
 {
   // TODO work with the stream
 }
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know that these classes are hardcoded in eclipse, thanks. In this case, I will maybe use the @SuppressWarnings annotation nonetheless.